# Alpha channel failing after Imagick update

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have an application that frequently uses Imagick's PHP module to recolor and composite images. I recently upgraded the server's software from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.0 and subsequently upgraded Imagick as well. I am now running ImageMagic 7.0.3 with the module 3.4.3. I have verified this in my site's phpinfo() and with the server command `convert -version`. The update for both was done in cPanel's WHM.

I use the following function to color an image using a given hex while preserving it's alpha shape and it's worked just fine up until updating.

```
protected function recolor($obj, $hex)
{
    $obj->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_EXTRACT);
    $obj->setImageBackgroundColor('#' . str_replace('#', '', $hex));
    $obj->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SHAPE);
    return $obj;
}
```

Example of image successfully recolored (pre-update):
[image]

Example of the same input with current behavior (post-update):
[image]

I'm not really sure what's causing this new behavior. There is definitely color being applied, but it's not being applied in the shape of the supplied image. In addition, everything that got recolored after the base layer (the first layer that gets recolored in this process) doesn't seem to be showing at all, with the only layers showing above being ones that are not recolored.

Edit: Here is one of the original input images that gets recolored:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyaoo.png - Base Color

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W1nr.png - Background (Composites under base)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUmWd.png - Lineart (Composites over base)

The composite process has been added below. First the function recolors all the applicable layer objects and then composites them and masks them to the "color" image (the "base" layer posted above in the shape of the wolf). Then that image is composited onto the background and the lines and logo added on top to create the final image.

```
$this->recolor($this->color, $baseHex);
$this->recolor($this->eyes, $eyesHex);
$this->recolor($this->eyebrows, $eyebrowsHex);
$this->recolor($this->pads, $padsHex);
$this->recolor($this->nose, $noseHex);
$this->recolor($this->claws, $clawsHex);
$this->recolor($this->tongue, $tongueHex);

$this->image->newImage(800, 598, new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$this->image->compositeImage($this->color, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->compositeMarkings();
$this->image->compositeImage($this->eyes, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->image->compositeImage($this->eyebrows, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->image->compositeImage($this->pads, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->image->compositeImage($this->nose, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->image->compositeImage($this->claws, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->image->compositeImage($this->tongue, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->mask($this->image, $this->color);
$this->bg->compositeImage($this->image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->bg->compositeImage($this->lines, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->bg->compositeImage($this->logo, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$this->bg->setImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);`
```

Comment: Post your input image, so we can test with it. IM 7.0.3.x is rather old and may have bugs. Can you upgrade to IM 7.0.6.9, the current version? Also, what is your exact minor version -- the x in my IM 7.0.3.x?

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for your comment! I've added the original base image to the original post. I hope that's what you meant. My exact version is `ImageMagick 7.0.3-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-09-16`

Comment: Please post your background image. If I understand you are using the alpha channel to do a -alpha shape and then perhaps compositing it over some background image. Is that correct? If not please tell me functionally what you are doing and provide all the input images. That way I can use IM 7.0.3.0 and test in the command line and compare to IM 7.0.6.9, the current version to see if it was a bug that got fixed or still a problem.

Comment: I've provided the background image that is composited on as well as the lineart that gets composited over the base layer. In addition, I've added the code that composites the image to better illustrate the process. Thank you so much for your help so far. The code typically layers quite a few images and I didn't think they'd all be necessary to test, but let me know if you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagemagick 7.0.3.0 has a bug and I can reproduce your issue in the command line.

```
magick 5W1nr.png \( iyaoo.png -alpha extract -background "#988777" -alpha shape \) -compose over -composite LUmWd.png  -compose over -composite result7030.png
```

[image]

But it works fine in the current Imagemagick 7.0.6.9 in the command line.

```
magick 5W1nr.png \( iyaoo.png -alpha extract -background "#988777" -alpha shape \) -compose over -composite LUmWd.png  -compose over -composite result7069.png
```

[image]

So I suggest you upgrade your version of Imagemagick